# Get URL Param Plugin and Inserting Result in Widget Code

Tags: shortcode, parameter

I am trying to insert the result from a Get Param plugin and insert it into a calendly widget on a WP page.

In a code module, if I write the plugin syntax of:
    `[urlparam param="Book" /]`

-and- the url of the page is:
    `https://www.example.com/booking/?Book=calendly.com/xxxxx`

...it displays the result correctly: **calendly.com/xxxxx**

Now, when I try and place that plugin syntax in the same module ***within*** widget code, it doesn't honor the expected result. Widget code (notice the urlparam after data-url=):

```
<!-- Calendly inline widget begin -->
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="[urlparam param="Book" /]" style="min-width:320px;height:580px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"></script>
<!-- Calendly inline widget end -->
```

Is there some kind of syntax I am missing for embedding this code within an inline widget code?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Thank you for the link. My apologies, I don't know PHP. Is PHP required in this case?

Comment: I think the underlying issue here is that [shortcodes are not evaluated when placed inside HTML attributes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/241637/2807). You could modify the template and output the necessary HTML using PHP and 
 `do_shortcode( '[urlparam param="Book" /]')` as an alternative approach.

Comment: Thank you, Dave. I'm new to PHP but can get around inside Divi Builder with most code. The do_shortcode you suggested above—I assume—is not to be pasted into the calendly widget code, but somewhere in some PHP file? I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Incorrect to use do_shortcode this way?  
`<!-- Calendly inline widget begin -->
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="do_shortcode( '[urlparam param="Book" /]')" style="min-width:320px;height:580px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"></script>
<!-- Calendly inline widget end -->`

Comment: Yes, this code should be added to a template file. There are workarounds to execute PHP in widgets, but this is not recommended. Your code is close, but the results of `do_shortcode()` are returned, so they must be echo'd to appear as output. I've added a full example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the underlying issue here is that [shortcodes are not evaluated when placed inside HTML attributes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/241637/2807). You could modify the template and output the necessary HTML using PHP and `do_shortcode( '[urlparam param="Book" /]')` as an alternative approach:

```
<!-- Calendly inline widget begin -->
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="<?php echo do_shortcode( '[urlparam param="Book" /]' ); ?>" style="min-width:320px;height:580px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"></script>
<!-- Calendly inline widget end -->
```

**Creating a plugin that contains a Calendly widget**

Another approach is to create a widget that outputs the desired HTML.

The code below can then be wrapped into a plugin by saving it to a file named `wpse-calendly.php` in a directory named `wpse-calendly`. Then, copy our custom Calendly plugin into the `plugins` directory, activate the plugin, and add the widget to the desired widget area.

Note that this solution still relies on the `urlparam` shortcode to function properly.

```
/**
 * Register WPSE_Calendly widget.
 */
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpse_register_calendly_widget' );
function wpse_register_calendly_widget() {
    register_widget( 'WPSE_Calendly_Widget' );
}

/**
 * Adds WPSE_Calendly widget.
 */

/**
 * Core class used to implement a WPSE Calendly widget.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget
 */
class WPSE_Calendly_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Sets up a new WPSE Calendly widget instance.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array(
            'description' => __( 'Display Calendly Widget.', 'wpse_calendly' ),
        );
        parent::__construct( 'wpse_calendly', __( 'Calendly', 'wpse_calendly' ), $widget_ops );
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the content for the current Calendly widget instance.
     *
     * @param array $args     Display arguments including 'before_title', 'after_title',
     *                        'before_widget', and 'after_widget'.
     * @param array $instance Settings for the current Calendly widget instance.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            $title = $instance['title'];
        }

        // Bail if the urlparam shortcode has not been registered.
        if ( ! shortcode_exists( 'urlparam' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );

        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( $title ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        }

        ?>
<!-- Calendly inline widget begin -->
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="<?php echo do_shortcode( '[urlparam param="Book" /]' ); ?>" style="min-width:320px;height:580px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"></script>
<!-- Calendly inline widget end -->
        <?php

        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
     * Handles updating settings for the current Calendly widget instance.
     *
     * @param array $new_instance New settings for this instance as input by the user via
     *                            WP_Widget::form().
     * @param array $old_instance Old settings for this instance.
     * @return array Settings to save or bool false to cancel saving.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] );

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the Calendly widget settings form.
     *
     * @param array $instance Current settings.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title_id = $this->get_field_id( 'title' );
        $instance['title'] = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';

        echo '<p><label for="' . $title_id .'">' . __( 'Title:', 'wpse_calendly' ) . '</label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="' . $title_id .'" name="' . $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) .'" value="' . $instance['title'] .'" />
        </p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: So glad we are close. I am embarrassed to ask where I would use the code you provided in last thread. You mention template file, as in a page template file? I haven't used one, yet. This requires FTP'ing into the folders etc. Yes?

Comment: I should clarify that I shouldn't use the term "widget". This is just a plain ol' code module on a page.

Comment: Yes, FTP is required unless the theme is being deployed in some other manner. Each theme is different, but a good place to start would be the theme's `sidebar.php` file.Generally, you would copy the wrapper HTML used by widgets and place the this code within the wrapper markup. Also note that you should not edit a theme directly unless you have authored it yourself. Otherwise, the changes will be lost when the theme is updated. Instead use a child theme.

Comment: This particular matter may be above my abilities. May have to hire a guru like yourself to look into it. Thanks so much for your time, Dave.

Comment: I felt like things started getting a little hairy there, so I've update my answer with a plugin that will do all the work for you. I *think* it will do the trick (I verified that it does try and load a Calendy instance, but I don't use their service).

Comment: Wow, Dave. You are the man. I still think this amazing code is above my ability to implement. Is it bad form to suggest hiring here in StackExchange. I sent you a private message in LinkedIn.